# Combo offer:Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout, price

Group 2 existing sku's together as one 'set' and sell them at one price together that is less than each of them sold separately.

Example: X is $20 and Y is $30. Buy Z (both X +Y) for $40.

Need separate product page for combo product.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found my answer.. It is possible with default magento itself.
So,
**Step 1:** I have created one group product(Made it enabled and in stock).
**Step 2:** Added associated product(All the product should be enabled and in stock)
**Step 3:** Now need to create the shopping cart price rule to give discount .
I have used sku to apply shopping cart price rule.
So I have created rule like this:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
        SKU  is  Test 12 

    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
        SKU  is  Test 13
```

**Step 4:** Now need to give action, means need to set the discount price.

So the rule will be if both the product exist in the cart the discount will be applied.

**Step 5:** So the functionality is all set,Now need to do some modification about how you r going to display to the customer that there is an offer if purchase that two product combinedly.

Answer (score 0):

"Bundle Product" is what you want.

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-bundle.html

Edit:

To achieve a lower price on the bundle, you can set a "fixed" price for it, which can be less than the sum of the two bundled items.

[image: Fixed bundle price]

Or, select the "dynamic" price option and put X % in the "Special Price" field.  This will make the price of the bundle X % of the sum of the two bundled items.

Comment: If I go with the bundle product, I will be not able to get the functionality. Because when u bundle the product the price will be increase with selecting the product.

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your comment.